# Getting Error: Missing ; in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium

I'm suing storeEval command using the javascript below:

```
Command: storeEval

Target : javascript{

var d= new Date();
var a= d.getDate();
var b= d.getMonth()+1;
var c=d.getFullYear();
var x=d.getHours();
var y= d.getMinutes();
var z= d.getSeconds();
var f=new String();
var s=f.concat(b+'/'+a+'/'+c);
var f1=new String();
var s1= f1.concat(x+':'+y+':'+z);
var time; 
if(x<12) {  time='Am'; } 
else { time='Pm'; }
var s2 = f1.concat(s+'\t'+s1+'\t'+time); s2

}

Value: abc
```

I'm getting the following error:

> [error] Threw an exception: missing ; before statement.

I'm storing the date in a variable `abc` so that I can so it further to match it with a label.

Kindly help.

Regards,

Anjali Vaswani

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
 Command: storeEval

 Target : javascript(var d= new Date();
 var a= d.getDate();
 var b= d.getMonth()+1;
 var c=d.getFullYear();
 var x=d.getHours();
 var y= d.getMinutes();
 var z= d.getSeconds();
 var f=new String();
 var s=f.concat(b+'/'+a+'/'+c);
 var f1=new String();
 var s1= f1.concat(x+':'+y+':'+z);
 var time; 
 if(x<12) {  time='Am'; } 
 else { time='Pm'; }
 var s2 = f1.concat(s+'\t'+s1+'\t'+time); s2)

 Value: abc
```

In java script used "()" instead of "{}". please let me know it work for you or not.

Answer (score 0):

The java script code you have posted has compilation problems. That is why you are getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
var s2 = f1.concat(s+'\t'+s1+'\t'+time); s2
```

This Line has Error. You have missing ';' after s2.
correct that and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Personally I got this error when trying to do something like this..

```
storedVars['currentRow'] = ${currentRow}+1
```

When I had renamed the variable further up the script, so altered the names and it worked fine

```
storedVars['currentUserRow'] = ${currentUserRow}+1
```

Also I am using the flow plugin and tried to use a **gotoIf** (GoToIf) command but found that I had to surround my variable in quotes, guessing it's so the string comparison works properly, [found this suggestion here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/oFUmVr-2Fxo)

```
"${moduleScore}" == "Not observed"
```